SSH from Macbook Pro to Fedora laptop times out in Terminal app
SSH from Macbook Pro to Fedora laptop times out consistently, when using SSH command from ZSH (Terminal app). Yet I'm able to connect to the Fedora laptop using my smartphone or even an SSH app on same Macbook. Same port, same Ip address, same credentials.
Initially I was able to rsync to same Fedora laptop just fine, then for no reason rsync failed in the middle, and since then neither SSH nor rsync work. Restarting Fedora laptop helps, but then after another rsync session not able to SSH again.
What can be a problem here?
ssh -vvv user@10.0.0.199                                                           
OpenSSH_9.8p1, OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/homebrew/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.0.0.199 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.199 [10.0.0.199] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.199 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.199 port 22: Operation timed out



Can the fedora machine ssh back to the Mac? I’ve not had to change my Mac, so perhaps check or document  the settings on Linux side.

yes, it can, even though rsync from Fedora to the Mac seems hanging without doing anything.

Please edit your question with the ouput of ssh -vvv ... Redact any private information.

You're running the Homebrew version of SSH. Please try with the built-in version (/usr/bin/ssh).

Built-in version made no difference. I think main issue here is rsync causes some kind of network hang on Mac side, so neither rsync nor ssh working until I restart the Linux machine.

There isn't much to go on here, but it sounds like the problem is on the Linux host. Maybe some kind of adaptive firewall that blocks simultaneous connections?

I doubt it's a Linux issue, since all other apps/machines connect to that laptop just fine, only Mac's Terminal app times out. There's only one connection which rsync makes I believe, internally rsync uses ssh, and looks like rsync just reuses same connection. For now I switched off WiFi on my laptop, and connected Ethernet, which gave me a new IP address. So far so good, no drop offs yet.

For now I switched off WiFi on my Linux laptop, and connected Ethernet, which gave me a new IP address. So far so good, no drop offs yet. Still not sure what's happening.

Maybe packets are getting fragmented. Try reducing the MTU on the Mac. See: https://www.dwthacker.com/finding-and-setting-mtu-on-mac
